# How to make Excel run in multi-CPU mode

Tags: excel, multithreading, multicore

I have big excel files, thousands lines and rows.
Gigs in size.
When i do work inside this files in excel, it throttling and lagging. Sometimes just get stucked ans freeze.

When i open a task manager, i see that Excel didnt eat even a one CPU.
RAM usage also not overloaded.

How to make excel use all my cores?

Excel 2019.

Answer (score 0):

1. I see you are familiar with Python. Why don't you move your databases to Python? Actually I don't know capability of it. I work in R. Some of my data in Excel and even in *.csv take 100-200 Mb, while in *.Rdata format the same information is less then 5Mb. R functions work faster then heavy Excel.
2. And yes, how to make excel use all cores of processor is interesting to me too.

Comment: I found only that all multithred and multi cpu option are turned off by default. So its not possible to do anything(

Comment: About python and R, it wil be absolutely another workflow with no gui. Analytics in my team better will wait for excel do slow.

Comment: Still no answer? Did you try to ask these guys:
1.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=all&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1
2.
https://powerspreadsheets.com/
3.
Sumit Bansal https://trumpexcel.com/about/
They are looks friendly. If you find the answer please let me know.

Comment: I just gave up. All multi thread a d multi cpu features are turned on by default. Only one thing i did is turned off hardware acceleratin. But in doesnt make any results. All multi-pulti excels thung works only for formula calculation, not for big data. So, guys, is like if you want more you should use a Power BI. But too many things we need to rewrite, so we just gave up and works with slow excel. Btw i tried many servers, up to 32 cores, virtual and hardware, all the same, excel just slow by themself.